# Cannot overload functions with generic type extending another type

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
public static testMethod<T extends MyModule.ITest>(fromArray: T): T;
public static testMethod<T extends MyModule.ITest>(fromArray: T[]): T[];
public static testMethod<T extends MyModule.ITest>(fromArray: (T|T[])): (T|T[])
{
    return null;
}

module MyModule
{
    export interface ITest
    {
    }
}
```

Typescript complains about "Duplicate identifier 'testMethod'" and "Function 'testMethod' declared a non-void return type, but has no return expression" on the return types of the body-less functions.  If I remove "extends ITest" from the generic type, everything seems to work.

Comment: The issue is with `IBase`. Can you add `IBase` and `ObservableArray` to your question. I'm guessing that `IBase` defines `deepCopyArray` in a way that is incompatible with `ObservableArray`.

Comment: IBase does not have a definition of deepCopyArray.  IBase is the type of the items in the ObservableArray and does not have any relation to deepCopyArray.  I have changed my question to show a simplified example that does not involve these  more complex types, which are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with "MyModule.ITest".  If I use "import ITest = MyModule.ITest;" and then say "extends ITest" instead of "extends MyModule.ITest", it compiles fine.

```
import ITest = MyModule.ITest;
module MyModule2
{
    public static testMethod<T extends ITest>(fromArray: T): T;
    public static testMethod<T extends ITest>(fromArray: T[]): T[];
    public static testMethod<T extends ITest>(fromArray: (T|T[]): (T|T[])
    {
        return null;
    }
}

module MyModule
{
    export interface ITest
    {
    }
}
```